# haskell make (class a) instance of other class'

Tags: class, haskell, types

Again Haskellers & Haskellettes,

I still have the problem, that I don't really know when to use `(Class a) => a`, `Type` or 
`Type a` where Type is a "union type" as for example `Val` and `ExprTree`

Now i want to make my datatype `ExprTree` a bit more versatile by adding a few instances:

```
import Ratio
data Fun = Add|Sub|Mul|Div|Pow
    deriving (Eq,Ord)
instance Show Fun where
    show Add = "+"
    show Sub = "-"
    show Mul = "*"
    show Div = "/"
    show Pow = "^"
type Label = Rational
type Var = String
class Eval e where
eval :: (Num a) => e -> a -> a
data ExprTree a = Leaf {lab::Label, val::Val a}
          | Node {lab::Label, fun::Fun, lBranch::ExprTree a, rBranch::ExprTree a}
          deriving(Eq,Ord)
data Val a = Num a | Var String deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

---

```
instance (Num a) => Num (ExprTree a) where
    ...
    fromInteger i = Leaf (0%1) i -- <--error

instance Show (ExprTree a) where
    show (Leaf l a) = show a -- <-- error
    show (Node l f lb rb) = (show lb)++"  "++(show l)
                      ++(show f)++"  "++(show rb)++"\n"

instance Eval (Val a) where
    eval (Var v) n = n
    eval a _ = a -- <-- error
```

I think this problems - are all of the same kind. And the NOT understanding the difference between class and type and so forth in a more than trivial setting - is a hole in the basis of my haskell programming; so i really want to understand this not to solve any homework.

Note: The label is a Rational - which makes inserting and searching much easier, than labelling with natural numbers or integers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that type of `eval` is what you want.  It's far too general, because it promises to work for any `a` and long as it's in `Num`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your `fromInteger` is that `i` needs to be converted to a `Val a`.

```
instance Num a => Num (ExprTree a) where
    -- ...
    fromInteger i = Leaf (0%1) (Val (fromInteger i))
```

The `Val` wrapper makes it a `Val`; the inner `fromInteger` creates an `a`, which is a caller-specified type, which we know can be created with `fromInteger` because of the `Num a` constraint) from the `Integer`.  Pay close attention to that last:  it's the reason behind typeclasses.  The `Num a =>` constraint insures that, given an `a`, we know that we can use any of the `Num` instance methods on it.

The other problem is the same issue in reverse:  you are calling `show`, but you haven't done anything to make sure that `show` makes sense on an `a`.

```
instance Show a => ExprTree a where
    show (Leaf _ a) = show a -- this works now because we told it a is show-able
    -- ...
```

The problem with `Eval` is slightly different:  `a` just appears without any source, so the compiler doesn't know anything about it.  In particular, `eval a _ = a` requires that an `e` be a valid `a` — but `a` is an unknown, so the compiler correctly says "what?".  For this one you need to think about what you're really trying to do; the simplest solution is to drop the `e` and use `a` everywhere, but is that really what you intended?

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the instance definition of `Num` is that you say you are showing
how any `ExprTree` is an instance of `Num` (meaning for any type `a`) but instead
you show how `ExprTree Integer` is an instance of Num. In other words, you can't
specialize that type variable if unless you want to declare your instance like
this:

```
instance Num (ExprTree Integer) where 
    ...
```

The Show instance has a sort of similar problem. You aren't showing how
`ExprTree a` is an instance of Show for any arbitrary `a`, you are showing it
only for `a`s which are instances of Show already. In other words, you would
need to change your instance declaration like so:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (ExprTree a) where
     ...
```

in order to make it work.

The third error in the Eval instance declaration comes from something unrelated
and rather mundane, basically you are taking a function of type a -> e -> e and
you are returning the first argument `a`. Haskell is confused, since you've
given it no indication that `a` and `e` are the same type, so there is no reason
it should accept values of type `a` as return types. (This might be just a case
of you getting a little confused. `eval` has the signature (Num e)=> e -> a ->
a, but you've named your first variable `a` in your instance declaration for
`Val a`.)

So, excluding the third instance declaration, your issue seems to be that you
are promising Haskell that you will declare an instance of a typeclass for a
very general type (like `ExprTree a` for any `a`) but then you renege on your
promise by requiring that the `a` be some more specific type like `Integer`